# iOS overflow-x (or position absolute) makes scrolling choppy?

Tags: iphone, ios, css, scroll

I want my webpage to be only scrollable vertically. So I've set `overflow-x:hidden;` to my `.page-wrapper`. My `.page-wrapper` holds two absolute positioned layers on top of each other. When clicking a button the top layer is sliding to the side (as mentioned `position:absolute;`) and makes the website actually wider than the 100% viewport witdh - so it would be scrollable horizontally.

To prevent the horizontal scrolling I've set `overflow-x:hidden` to my `.page-wrapper`.

If I do that, the vertical scrolling of my normal content is really buggy and doesn't work correctly.

Any ideas how to fix that?

**UPDATE**

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` seems to work fine as long no javascript is changing any heights. See the following example. What I'm doing here is updating the height of the body to the contents-height of the second layer - so there is no empty scrolling space once the upper layer is slid to the left. When sliding the upper layer back I remove the attribte `style` (which sets the height) from the body. After doing that the scroll is choppy again.

```
function showInfos(show) {

    if ( show ) {
        $('#videos').addClass('slid');
        $('body').height($('#infos > .content').height());
        $('#page-wrap').addClass('no-overflow');
    } else if ( !show ) {
        $('#videos').removeClass('slid');
        $('#page-wrap').removeClass('no-overflow');
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
    }
}
```

Comment: set the height to 100%. Then you can set the overflow to auto

Comment: I've set the height of my body and the elements to `100%` but that is not what I mean. The page is still wider than the viewport and therefore it automatically is scrollable horizontally as well. I just don't want that to happen. I don't want any horizontal scrolls on my site (because I'm doing swipe and other gestures via javascript). That's why I thought I could simply set `overflox-x:hidden` so this problem would be solved - and it is - however the next problem occurs which is choppy vertical scrolling.

Comment: Moreover, I just tested this and even `overlow:auto` makes the scrolling choppy - in this case x-wise and y-wise.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could try setting `width:100%` on `.page-wrapper` and set that to `overflow:hidden` and `position:relative`. That might prevent the horizontal scroll.

#### Updated 10/12/2012

Thanks for the code example. It really helped me see your intent and the issue with scrolling more clearly. It looks like you need [-webkit-overflow-scrolling](http://johanbrook.com/browsers/native-momentum-scrolling-ios-5/). Add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to `page-wrapper`. Here's an [updated test page] with that rule applied. You can compare with test page in my comment below to see the difference.

Comment: I do have already `width:100%` to `.page-wrapper`. Also `overflow-x:hidden` is set to `.page-wrapper` -> all mentioned above. And even `position:relative` is set to `.page-wrapper`, because the layers inside of `.page-wrapper` are positioned absolutely within `.page-wrapper`. First off, when applying `overflow:hidden` I can't scroll vertically any longer - I need to scroll vertically but don't want any horizontal scroll at all.

Comment: Interesting. I put up a [little test page](http://mcelweewebdesign.com/test/test_stack-20121011.html). Is this along the lines of what you're trying to do? Vertical scrolling is possible on my example, though on desktop browsers (FF & Chrome) the scroll bar didn't show at small window widths.

If this isn't on target, can you post your work in progress or a test case to see if there's something else causing the issue?

Answer (score 58):

Try applying it to every element:

```
* {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: I dont know why someone gave -1 for this answer.. it solved my problem directly. +1

Comment: Indeed it is :), well you shouldn't set it to all elements. That's why i guess it got -1.

Comment: It helped me adding this to `body`.

Comment: Yes you've saved my day, if's been hours that I'm looking to this solution on the net

Comment: I agree that this solved my problem too. However, what I don't understand is why it is necessary to add it to each element and why it's not the default case? I mean if iOS is such buggy why is it necessary to assign this property even if it isn't a scrollable element?

Comment: @julmot because the web is made not just for the iOS

Comment: yes but this property is supported only in safari according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: This help! Thanks

Comment: Find the proper elements to set this on... Not ALL Elements.

Answer (score 1):

This done the job for me so that it's not a problem on any page:

```
html {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had this issue on a Bootstrap 4.5 template: whenever I added 'overflow-x:hidden;' to .page-wrapper, the scrolling on iPhone was not smooth anymore but choppy.

But when I removed 'overflow-x:hidden;' from .page-wrapper, on iPad the user could move the page horizontally, which is not desired.

The solution of Tim was a great direction, the minimal solution for me was to add these two pieces in my CSS file:

**AT THE TOP OF CSS:**

```
html, body {width:100%; height:100%;}
```

**AND IN THE CSS:**

```
.page-wrapper { 
/** overflow-x: hidden; GIVES ISSUES WITH IPHONE!!! **/

    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    
    position:relative; 
    overflow-x:hidden; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

**Don't forget to put in the index.html:**

```
<META name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no'>
```

Answer (score -2):

TLDR; apply `transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px)` to the element and the wrapper.

In my case, an absolute or fixed position element was hidden behind the main page by having a smaller z-index. The result is that when the wrapper was moved out of the way to revel the element, and then moved back, on iOS there was a delay when trying to scroll over where that element was. I *could* scroll, but I had to hold down for about a second.

The solution described here worked for me:
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/mobile-safari-iphone-issue-with-position-fixed-content-running-over-the-top/

Basically, both the element and the element's wrapper need to have the style `transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px)` applied, then the scrolling went smoothly. For me, without applying it to both the element and the wrapper, the fix didn't work.

Comment: Offtopic, but for 15 seconds of laughs apply that `transform` to `*`. On the oldest and slowest device you can find. It looks amazing.