# webkit-overflow-scrolling issue with x-axis?

Tags: ios, css, webkit

I have a scrollable div with the following css:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
width:200px;
height:500px;
```

However on iOS devices, when the content inside of the div is wider than the div itself, x-axis scrolling is enabled. How do I disable x-axis scrolling?

Comment: This might show some insight.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845892/ios-overflow-x-or-position-absolute-makes-scrolling-choppy

Answer (score 10):

I've been having the same problem and it seems that there are no x/y options for -webkit-overflow-scrolling unfortunately. The workaround I typically use is to wrap the scrolling div in an `overflow-x: hidden` div and problem should be solved.

Markup:

```
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <div class="scroll-body">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
.scroll-container {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
.scroll-wrapper {
   width: 200px;
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score -6):

A really easy fix for this is just to make sure none of your elements are wider than the viewport. This can be accomplish by placing a "catchall" at the top of your CSS:

```
div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, img, ul, li, ... ETC ...
{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thats just horrid and will bite you later.

Comment: Good idea for specific classes though. Solved an Ionic problem for me. Thank you.

Comment: Haha, I earned lots of money to fix problems that were caused by code like this.