# multiple floated divs-overflow hidden, partial view

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float, overflow

Here's the set up:

I have a 100% width div that allows for the input of multiple images (this is in wordpress). I have a class set up that floats those images left. The overflow is hidden, but I want the full width to fill up and show only part of the last image.

The code as it is now works great, but only displays the last image if it fully fits and leaves empty space until the browser window is large enough to take another image. I'm basically setting up a banner that's a collage of images of equal height, but variably width. He'll put in enough images so that it's one continuous banner.

Here's the css (the class repeats in the id):

```
#banner {clear:both;height:250px;width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
.banner-image {float:left;}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**Html**

```
<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img class="banner-image" src="somsrc"/>
        <img class="banner-image" src="somsrc"/>
        <img class="banner-image" src="somsrc"/>
        <img class="banner-image" src="somsrc"/>
        <img class="banner-image" src="somsrc"/>
        <!-- add more images here -->
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.maincontainer {
    height:250px;width:100%;overflow:hidden;
}
.imagecontainer {
    width:1000%; /* NOTE very wide div that is overflowing */
    clear:both;
}
.banner-image {
    float:left;
    background:#f00;
    margin-right:3px;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMJwT/2/). Depending on your screen width you may have to adjust the size of the browser to see the image clipping.

Comment: A slight variation worked like a charm, thanks! Weird for a new programmer to think about something being more than 100%.

Comment: bummer. Doesn't work on in iOS (stretches to 1000%). Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, you may need to play around with -webkit-overflow-scrolling. There is more information about this at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845892/ios-overflow-x-or-position-absolute-makes-scrolling-choppy). It seems people have solved this issue, so with a little playing around I'm sure you'll sort it. Good luck :)

Comment: tried a bunch of stuff and even a few plugins to no avail. Started fresh, recoded the section of the template with pretty much your code line for line and it resolved the issue! THANKS dcarson! My variation was lazy, but worked everywhere but iOS, should have stuck with yours to begin with:)