# Overflow-x value ignored in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, ios, css, html, mobile-safari

We set the overflow-x values to hidden on both the body and scrollable elements, but mobile Safari ignores these values. On the desktop, the overflow values work fine.

Relevant code:

```
body { overflow-x:hidden; width:320px; height:100%; min-height:100%; margin:0; background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#e8e4dc,#f2f0eb); }

.page_list, .content { max-height:370px; box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch }

#catalog_page { border-left:1px solid #CCC; z-index:28; position:absolute; top:0; width:200px; height:460px; background:white; -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.1s ease-in;; -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); display:none; }
```

catalog_page is what sits outside the viewport, sliding into view only after someone does a gesture.

To reproduce:

1) Visit [www.tekiki.com](http://tekiki.com) on your iPhone (not iPad). Scroll to the right, and you'll see how catalog_page extends the site's width, even though we fixed the body width.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `html { overflow: hidden; }` to your CSS and it should fix it.

Comment: awesome, thanks! we tried overflow-x on the HTML element before, and it didn't work? why does this fix this? btw, could you also email me at info at panabee.com? would like to ask a quick question. thanks!

Comment: I would also add "overflow-y: auto" so you can scroll up and down.

Comment: Wow, thanks! All of the hacks for this problem are terrible. This worked perfectly (iOS 10 here). Also, I'm only using `overflow-x` and it works just as well.

Comment: this work but in ios the soft scroll is disabled , any solution?

Answer (score 4):

It's 2020 but I am still trying to find an answer for this.

After many experiments, I found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39924900/10668706) was actually the only working one.

However, it does create an odd black bar across the whole page in all browsers. Also, you should not use units for zero values.

Therefore, my final solution is this: (any transform function should do the trick, just remember to set zero values.)

```css
html, body {
    ... (font, background, stuff)

    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Safari compatibility */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Be aware, this solution may influence on your navigation.
"position: fixed;" will not work on children because of "transform" property set something other than "none"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! Adding the transform there fixed the issue I had with Safari ignoring my overflow-x: hidden.

Comment: Also be aware that setting `overflow-x: hidden` on the `html` element will break any use of `position: sticky` on elements within. Unfortunately Safari has turned into the new IE :(

Answer (score 3):

Tested with Mobile Safari on iOS 7.1/8.2
Following code didn't work for me neither.

> html { overflow: hidden; }

I believe it's a bug/feature of Mobile Safari, other browsers, including Safari on OSX works well. But the overflow:hidden works on iPhone/iPad if you also set position:fixed to HTML element. Like this:

> html { overflow: hidden; position: fixed; }

Answer (score 2):

> Add html { overflow: hidden; } to your CSS and it should fix it.

This solution didn’t work for me.

Instead, i create a wrapper div inside the body and apply the overflow-x:hidden to the wrapper :

**CSS**

```
#wrapper { 
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**html**

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the down vote ? This solution works for me and not the one which is accepted.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Content just overflows and I get a huge scroll. It's honestly only applicable in very specific scenarios.

Comment: @Hugo Could you show an example ? Like i said, it worked for me and not the accepted answer.

Comment: I had a div with `width:3000px; position: absolute; bottom: 0;` Dunno if that enough to reproduce the non-applicability, or if other elements in my DOM made a difference.

Comment: @Hugo Could you make a simple fiddle ? I would like to try.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that same code anymore, I went around the issue with some large rewrites. I would have created one if I still had it.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, the following did solve the problem

```
body, html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Obviously, this did not work for the safari version 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had the following code to disable double-tap to zoom:

```css
* {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

This broke overflow scrolling though. Here’s how I fixed it:

```css
pre {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  touch-action: pan-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually gave up on css overflow-x in IOS safari.
I used script instead

```
$(window).scroll(function ()
{
    if ($(document).scrollLeft() != 0)
    {
        $(document).scrollLeft(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022. Mobile safari can still be quirky. But it seems for me the way to get overflow-x working on the body is to do the following:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I wish I understood the transform, but it seems necessary. The other way was to set the body to position of relative, but this seems safer.

OR

Another way thats definitely safe, and future proof, is to place everything in body directly into a div and give that div an overflow of hidden and make sure it has a min-height of 100vh. Like so:

```
<body>
  <div class="page">
    everything...
  </div>
</body>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.page {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to solve the issue on older devices (iphone 3) as well I had to mix the solutions, because they didn't work singularly.

I ended up adding a wrapper div to the html body:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">....</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and styling it with:

```
#wrapper { 
  overflow: hidden 
}
```

and it finally worked.

Answer (score -1):

If html, body `overflow-x: hidden;` is not working for you try looking for text-indent. The default settings of flexslider for example have some elements set to `text-indent -9999px`. I found this was overriding html overflow rules.