# iOS Safari Vertical Scrolling Feels Sticky (With No Momentum)

Tags: ios, safari, scroll, overflow

I've got a problem with vertical scroll in iOS Safari on a web page: while being scrolled, page moves in a very slow way, with high resistance (such behavior is not usual for iOS browsers)

My attempts to locate the problem:

```
<!-- piece of HTML listing -->
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
          (here goes some content)
    </div>
</body>
```

I detected the problem in the `overflow-x:hidden;` rule for `div#wrapper`, changing it to 'overflow:hidden;' or removing it dynamically in web debugging panel.

Is there any chance to fix it without changing the page layout?

Repeats on Safari / iOS 6.1.4 and 7 (both iPad and iPhone), also in iOS Simulator on OS X.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your webpage?

Comment: Check this post out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845892/ios-overflow-x-or-position-absolute-makes-scrolling-choppy

Gianluca.

Answer (score 17):

You can try to add the webkit specific css line to you div:

```
#wrapper{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

read more about momentum and ios scrolling here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/

Comment: Saved my day. You can also automate this with PostCSS: https://github.com/solversgroup/postcss-momentum-scrolling